# Spring binding multiple attributes to same @ModelAttribute

Tags: spring, modelattribute

I have a preview page which takes add or edit models and displays the preview.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/preview", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView preview(@ModelAttribute("editForm") FormModel editFormModel) {
        //action
    } 

@RequestMapping(value = "/preview", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView preview(@ModelAttribute("addForm") FormModel addFormModel) {
        //action
    }
```

I need to call preview from add form page and edit form page. The models I'm going to pass are same but come from different forms.

(1) Is there a way ModelAttribute supports this kind of multi-attribute name mapping? 
(2) How can I think about redesigning this? Thinking about (a) Renaming the form name/attribute before form submit to use the same attribute name. (b) Remove ModelAttribute altogether - That's not an option for me as I'm using spring mvc form binding.

Note: I'm using editForm/addForm as session attributes.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think the model attributes are used as part of the routing logic, so spring can't determine which of the two identical mappings to route a preview POST to. You need to think of this from a REST perspective -- one of these things should be a POST, the other a PUT. Getting that right will inform your decision about the model attributes...

Comment: @EngineerDollery, I agree with  on the routing logic part. We SHOULD NOT (in my case, CAN NOT) use ModelAttribute to determine which method to route to. My intention is only to capture same form model (types) with different attribute names into the same method.

Answer (score 0):

Not actually solutions but work arounds.

**Approach 1:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/preview", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ModelAndView preview(@ModelAttribute("editForm") FormModel editFormModel) {
    //action
} 

@RequestMapping(value = "/preview", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView preview(@ModelAttribute("addForm") FormModel addFormModel) {
    //action
}
```

**Approach 2:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editpreview", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ModelAndView preview(@ModelAttribute("editForm") FormModel editFormModel) {
    //action
} 

@RequestMapping(value = "/addpreview", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView preview(@ModelAttribute("addForm") FormModel addFormModel) {
    //action
}
```